# I am getting HTML response through web service

Tags: iphone

I am getting HTML response through web service and I want xml from web method. I am using TBXML xml parser. It occurs occasionally, such as in this example:

The resource cannot be found.body{font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}b{font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}..............................................................
pls help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like a web-service Error to me, what's the problem ?

Comment: Its a soap based web service written in .NET. It's supposed to return some data in xml data, but it returns some HTML/JavaScript code when consumed from an iPhone App.

Comment: Although this web method is giving correct result (in xml) when tested on development system.

Comment: you're just using the webService wrongly

Comment: If the webservice suppose to send XML but you see an error HTML you're asking a wrong request. E.g. ask by POST an url with a GET method.

Comment: I have double checked this, but it is still the same. Can you suggest anything else that you think may be wrong.